# Why no current in neutral wire_kids question

Tags: neutral

One school child asked me -

If current means flow of electrons, or entering to a bulb from one wire (Live) then going back through another wire, then why there is no current in the neutral wire, because electrons or charges is still flowing through it as part of going back?

I could not answer him, so kindly advise, what exactly the neutral line is, what is happening in neutral wire , why it is important for , why it has no electricity?
Kindly provide a simple answer (if possible some examples with water or other comparable things)

Comment: "there is no current in the neutral wire" where does this assumption come from?

Comment: Ahhh.  Take a look at those wires.  If there were no current flowing through the neutral, then you could use a **much** thinner wire for neutral.  But, neutral is as thick as the live.  Current **does** flow through the neutral.  The **voltage** on the neutral is very close to zero **as measured between neutral and the literal ground beneath your feet.** That's because neutral is connected to the earth ground wire in your house, and earth ground is connected to the **literal ground beneath your feet.**

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of what current and voltage are.  The child doesn't know - hasn't had a chance to learn it.  If you are a science teacher, then you need to improve your **own** understanding of voltage and current.

Comment: [Here is a good summary of electricity and home wiring.](http://www.kevinboone.net/electricity.html)

Comment: We had a good demonstration in class - Van der Graff generator with all the class on rubber mats & holding hands except for the one at the end who stood on the floor... Then the teacher touched the generator - no one noticed except the kid at the end :) I suppose this would be a banned activity by the H&S police now...

Comment: Well, once you start filling any empty glass with a Jug of water, water will be there in both glass and jug. Anyway, I think he is asking why there is no voltage in neutral.

Comment: Has the child seem drawing of the wiring? or only had verbal discussions?USA has +-110 volts, with a neutral, coming to homes. Any imbalances, such as 1 bulb on one half, and 13 bulbs on the other half, results in  lots of imbalance. Even is the load needs 220 and thus is wired across the two hot wires, there will always be electric-field imbalances which causes small currents in the neutral wire.

Answer (score 5):

> ... then why there is no current in the neutral wire?

Yes, Virginia, there is a current.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes,_Virginia,_there_is_a_Santa_Claus)</sup>.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa8Q9r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The building supply comes from the utility company's transformer. One of the transformer outputs is connected to earth and so is "neutralized.*

Current must return to the source as you suspect. The pupil may be getting confused with *voltage* and since the neutral wire is connected to earth there is, nominally, no voltage on the neutral wire with respect to earth. In practice the neutral wire has some resistance so a voltage proportional to the current (V = IR, Ohm's Law) will appear at the lower terminal of the lamp. This shouldn't be more than a couple of volts in normal operation.